# Gnuplot grid overlap with text

Tags: grid, gnuplot, overlap

I am currently using gnuplot for multiple graphs of some text data. Therefore I want to add a grid for a better view of the data. However the grid gets too close to the text of the line. How can I improve it, so there are no grids in the area of the text?

Comment: Can you provide an example?  That would be very helpful to me at least to see what you're talking about.

Answer (score 1):

You can draw a rectangle around the tex

```
set grid

mylabel="blub"
set obj 10 rect at 0,0 size char strlen(mylabel), char 1 
set obj 10 fillstyle solid border -1 front
set label 10 at 0,0 mylabel front center

plot sin(x)
```

More examples on how to draw rectangles can be found [here](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo/rectangle.html).

Answer (score 1):

Version 5.0 introduced an option `boxed` for labels, which allows adding a background to labels. The actual box settings are done with `set style textbox`:

```
set grid lw 2
set style textbox opaque noborder
set label at 0,0 "mylabel" boxed center front
plot sin(x)
```

[image]